Escape criteria for "Mandelbrot-type" sets for trancendental entire functions
I have been experimenting with some fractal-generating software (escape time fractals, mostly with programs like XaoS, UltraFractal, ChaosPro, Fractal Science Kit), with other functions than polynomials, more precisely trancendental entire functions (TEF). It have been interesting and I have obtained some nice pictures, and even for fun done some mathematics on a few cases. But I have one problem: the choice and interpretation of the escape criteria.
I have mostly used (for some of the programs it seems to be the only option) variants of the traditional large values criteria with various large values even through I doubt it is the best choice. I know that these criteria does not give the same info for TEFs as for polynomials. TEFs have essential singularities at $\infty$ instead of an attractive fixed point (Picard's theorem), and futhermore $\infty$ is included in the Julia sets. Still, the large values criteria has given very nice sets, so it would be sligthly annoying if it didn't signify something.
I guess that one way of seeing it is that if an set gives the parameters $c$ having bounded orbit then the set would include all parameters giving (asymptotic) periodic orbits? But can more be said... or has already been said? I haven't found very much on generalized Mandelbrot sets on the net (this thread was a nice read through). Most stuff I found was on Julia sets. Not useless at all, but not what I was looking for.
If the answer is negative, I personally still think these objects ("Mandelbrot-type" sets defined from large values escape criterias or other alternatives derived purely from the orbits, instead of properties for the corresponding Julia sets) are worth studying for the fractal qualities of the sets alone. Most of my runs have given sets that do not look like the classical Mandelbrot set, but seems to be just as intricate. For me, that is enough to qualify as interesting. I am the type of mathematician who value beauty, facinating details and unexpectedness in explicit examples just as much (maybe even more when deciding wether to take a deeper look at the subject) than usefullness, generality or cross-area qulities.

maybe search on the keyword bifurcation locus (famous example is the boundary of the Mandelbrot set)

Thanks for the tips. I will do that
